# Installation of MongoDB fails on CentOS 7

Tags: mongodb, centos7

I am new to MongoDB and trying to install V5 on CentOS 7 Server. I am using the official documentation to install MongoDB from here:https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/
When I try to run the MongoDB, I run the following command (as per the spec):

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

unfortunately, this does not succeed and I get the follow error:

```
Job for mongod.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The command

```
systemctl status mongod.service
```

reveals the following:

```
mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Sat 2022-10-22 06:51:02 UTC; 8min ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 22590 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=killed, signal=ILL)
  Process: 22587 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 22585 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 22583 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 22 06:51:02 server1.bjmanch.in systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
Oct 22 06:51:02 server1.bjmanch.in systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=killed status=4
Oct 22 06:51:02 server1.bjmanch.in systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
Oct 22 06:51:02 server1.bjmanch.in systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Oct 22 06:51:02 server1.bjmanch.in systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
```

And, that's where I am completely stuck from last 3 days.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check the logfile, typically at `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, thanks for your input but there are no logs in this log file. It is just empty - size is 0.

Comment: Try to start it  manually `/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`

Comment: No luck. I got the message "Illegal instruction"

Comment: Then try `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf --logpath /proc/$$/fd/0`